# 'Non sono essere'

Tags: grammar, agreement, grammatical-number

I have come across [this example](https://www.secoloditalia.it/2017/08/tutto-il-dolore-del-padre-di-niccolo-ciatti-e-il-dramma-della-fidanzata/):

> "**Non sono essere** umani ma bestie che hanno ammazzato mio figlio come
> un sacco di patate, non posso dire neanche come un cane perché neanche
> un cane si merita una fine così".

I know what the sentence means, but the construction `non sono essere` makes no sense to me. I first thought it's a typo, but then found other examples in the 'Net.

Answer (score 5):

It's a typo, no doubt. It should be *Non sono esseri umani, ma bestie che...*, that is, “Those are not human beings, but beasts, who...”.

<sub>As for other examples in the web, you are free to ask about them, but keep in mind that, given any possible typo, Google will find it thousands of times.</sub>